# Sample space of an experiment

Tags: probability

In any probabilistic model,do a finite sample space always corresponds to discrete sample space & an infinite sample space always corresponds to a continuous sample space and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite implies discrete.

But infinite does not imply continuous. For example, toss a fair coin until you get a head. Then the number of tosses can be $1,2,3,4,\dots$ but the distribution is discrete, not continuous. In general when the sample space is countable, then the distribution is discrete.

Continuous does imply infinite.

Note that there are distributions that are neither discrete nor continuous.

Comment: Thanks!I was unaware of the fact that there are distributions that are neither discrete nor continuous.Could you please give a few _examples_? I want to have a look at them.

Comment: Imagine putting in a new lightbulb, and let $T$ be its total useful life. Maybe the bulb is defective (say probability $1/10$), in which case its total life $T$ is $0$. Or maybe it is not defective, in which case $T$ is exponentially distributed. Then the random variable $T$ is kind of a mixture between continuous and discrete. This kind of random variable comes up surprisingly often in applications, for example when insurance payments have a cap.

Comment: And then there are distributions like the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) which are in a sense continuous but not absolutely continuous so do not have a density function